# Defining and casting a class by its name

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have these lines

```
MyClassA *object = [[MyClassA alloc] init];
MyClassB *object = [[MyClassB alloc] init];
MyClassC *object = [[MyClassC alloc] init];
...
```

that I want to transform to a generic method to create an object from the class name.

suppose I have this

```
NSString *className = @"MyClassA"
```

How do I create this line

```
MyClassA *object = [[MyClassA alloc] init];
```

this part `[[MyClassA alloc] init]` is easy, cause I can do

```
[[NSClassFromString(className) alloc] init]
```

but what about the

`MyClassA *object` part?

```
??????????? = [[NSClassFromString(className) alloc] init];
```

What do I put on the question marks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In its simplest and most generic form:

```
id object = [[NSClassFromString(className) alloc] init];
```

But really you should provide some more information and formality by creating a protocol which describes the common things that these classes will provide, so you would have something like:

```
id < MyClass > object = [[NSClassFromString(className) alloc] init];
```

and

```
@protocol MyClass < NSObject >

// method definitions supported by all classes

@end
```

(and your MyClassA/B/C would implement the protocol)

Comment: Fantastic the idea of defining a protocol. It will be more or less like casting for what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`id object`, but you will not be able to "cast" using a string.

If you then need to call a method on that id object do this:

```
if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(myMethod:)])
    [object performSelector:@selector(myMethod:) withObject:@"param1"];
```

Check first if the object responds to that selector and invoke it.

I don't know what you are trying to solve, but before using this approach, evaluate alternative solutions that don't involve what i've just described :)